# No access on networked laptops

Tags: wordpress, networking, uwamp

I've created a Wordpress development site in UWAMP which works perfectly.  It is in the main www directory, not a virtual host folder.  Networked computers cannot access it at all on 127.0.0.1 but I CAN see the UWamp www index.php page on the networked machine if I go to 192.168.1.10 (my internal IP) and if I ..hide my web index.php file, therefore calling the uwamp index.php by default. But if I replace the default with my site index.php I get the "localhost refused connection" message.  I have de-activated firewalls on both machines, no difference. If I install some static html pages, even within nested folders, they show up fine in the networked machines.  Please can someone point me in the right direction to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.  I hadn't thought to change the url home page entry in the wordpress database.  Once I did that, bingo!